# Hibernate. Keep reference to last child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have simple Parent-Child relationship with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations.

```
@Entity
public class Parent { 
       @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class Child {
      @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
      @JoinColumn( name = "parent_id" )
      @ForeignKey( name = "fk_child_parent" )
      private Parent parent;

}
```

But I also want to keep reference to current(last) child inside `Parent` entity.

How to do it in right way? Should I introduce new undirectional `@OneToOne`relationship in `Parent`? Like this:

```
   @OneToOne( optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn( name = "current_child_id", nullable = false )
   @ForeignKey( name = "FK_parent_child" )
   private Child currentChild;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are always gonna have the issue of determining the insertion order of child elements for existing parent's and children on application start. You should therefore have this data preserved in your persistence layer.

Add a created (or updated) timestamp to your child class, you can determine for yourself how you want to handle the initialization of this field (i.e. with column defaults or triggers etc.). Now the required information should be available to you in your code, just add a 'compareTo' method to your Child (to sort) and add the following a `getMostRecentChild` method to your Parent class.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Child getMostRecentChild() {
        if(children == null || children.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return Collections.sort(children).get(0);
    }
}

public class Child {
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn( name = "parent_id" )
    @ForeignKey( name = "fk_child_parent" )
    public Parent parent;

    @Column( name = "created_ts" )
    public createdTs;

    public int compareTo(Child other) {
        return created_ts.compareTo(other);
    }

}
```

The implementation details for how you find the currentChild are irrelevant. You could also use a TreeSet or just a loop to find the currentChild.

EDIT: Argument why this is better than a currentChild column.

If you don't like the above answer consider the following

1. Adding a currentChild field provides two references to the same object. It is therefore not normalized, whereas, adding a timestamp adds a normalized column to your schema from which the information you require (and more) can easily be derived in a way that is directly coupled to the logic you are attempting to encapsulate in your currentChild column.
2. In order to ensure that your currentChild doesn't mismatch from it's intended value, you must encapsulate it's logic in either the Hibernate object, which you can then override on a database level, or with triggers on a database level, which can be ugly and hard to trace (whereas a default value and 'ON UPDATE' for created_ts field is fairly common place)

Comment: Can you please explain why I should make fields public or move annotations to getters/setters? What is wrong with keeping them on private fields?

Comment: You need the getters/setter to access the fields in your code anyways, I remember from last I used Hibernate putting the annotations on the getter's, however, on second look it seems like you can put the annotations on the private field as well and hibernate will use reflection to set the fields.

Comment: Edited to provide better explanation on these choices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a List, you can just look at the last element of the list.

You will want Hibernate to maintain the list order by adding @OrderColumn(name="INDEX_COL") below the @OneToMany